# How to change output\input template in foogallery with hooks?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need change output template. For example:

Now I have this template which a store in database

```
<div id="foogallery-gallery-67" class="foogallery-container foogallery-default foogallery-link-image foogallery-lightbox-foobox-free spacing-width-10 hover-effect-zoom3  border-style-square-white alignment-center hover-caption-simple foogallery-default-loading">
    <a  href="http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/222-1.jpg" data-caption-title="Title" data-caption-desc="description text" data-attachment-id="128" class="">
        <img  src="http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/cache/2017/08/222-1/705461751.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I need add one data-* attribute (data-custom)

```
<div id="foogallery-gallery-67" class="foogallery-container foogallery-default foogallery-link-image foogallery-lightbox-foobox-free spacing-width-10 hover-effect-zoom3  border-style-square-white alignment-center hover-caption-simple foogallery-default-loading">
    <a  href="http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/222-1.jpg" data-caption-title="Title" data-caption-desc="description text" data-attachment-id="128" data-custom="" class="">
        <img  src="http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/cache/2017/08/222-1/705461751.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I know that I can add directly to the database, I'm interested in how can redefine the output and input function so that in the future there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And again I will answer my own question

For example we have such a structure of the plugin:

```
class Plugin()
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}

$startPlugin = new Plugin();
```

And we need to change output `FooGallary` template. `FooGallary` have this filter, who can change output tamplate `foogallery_attachment_html_link_attributes`. Now change our class, with help this filter.

```
class Plugin()
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter('foogallery_attachment_html_link_attributes', array($this, 'addFoogalleryCategory'), 10, 3);
    }

    public function addFoogalleryCategory($attr, $args, $attachment)
    {
        $attr['data-category'] = 'category';
        return $attr;
    }
}

$startPlugin = new Plugin();
```

It's very easy, but I did not immediately find a solution. Maybe I helped someone.